# Is there a CDS view annotation (ABAP) to remove/select a field?

Tags: eclipse, annotations, abap, cds

I created an ABAP CDS view from a dataset. This dataset contains data with a field "OrderID" (from order 1 to order 10000). Based on this field, OrderID, I would like to create 2 query views : one containing only data from order 1 to 20 and another one with order 50 to 70.

Therefore, I was wondering if there is an annotation to select the value I want to show/remove. I don't want to filter for performance reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `where` clause, [as described in the ABAP keyword documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abencds_f1_where_clause.htm?file=abencds_f1_where_clause.htm):

```
define view first_query_view as
  select from your_base_view
    { ... }
    where OrderID between 1 and 20;

define view second_query_view as
  select from your_base_view
    { ... }
    where OrderID between 50 and 70;
```

Annotations explain how views and the elements in them are to be used. They don't control how the data is retrieved, joined, or filtered.